# ifind process utilises 97% of CPU

Tags: cpu, macos

I have mbp13 2019 with i7 16gb RAM running MacOs Catalina (10.15.7).

There is an `ifind` process started from `root` on `34` port and this process utilises CPU heavilly. It could work for 40 minutes in a row and it makes mbp really hot.

I tried to google it but I found no information about this process. It looks look like it is a some system process and I'm trying to find out how to make it use less of CPU.

I have mbp13 late 13 with the same OS and I have no issues with this process. And my previous corporate laptop also had not any issues with ifind. Corporate support tells that it might be a backup process, but backup is scheduled on a different time.

There is no logged in AppleId on this mac so it looks like it couldn't be a "Find my mac" process.

Does anyone know something about `ifind`?

Comment: Can you check what command is being run? [This question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/162154/24324) has information on how.

Comment: iFind looks like a 3rd party app for web searches - https://ifind.en.softonic.com/mac It also appears on the App Store - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/ifind/id512550638?mt=12 It looks suspiciously under-subscribed & has been kicking around the net for decades - https://mac.majorgeeks.com/files/details/ifind.html

Answer (score 2):

I was just having this issue as well, and I suspect your corporate support is correct: it likely has to do with Commvault backup software. Web searches suggest that (a) the "ifind.exe" process on Windows is evidently notorious for consuming CPU, and (b) ifind exists as a process for the Unix version of Commvault. (I only found references to ifind in the Solaris and FreeBSD versions, but it's reasonable to assume the Mac version was ported from their earlier Unix versions.) It looks like "ifind" is the process that collects changed files to be backed up.

If this process is "stuck" it's probably an issue to take up with IT. For me, it cleared up once the backup to the server was well underway.

(I do see this is a relatively old question, but someone else may find this later.)